# Apache subdomain problem

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, virtualhost

Sorry if this is answered somewhere else but can't figure it out. Cant get my server to respond on the subdomain, only the main domain. Relevant info below, if you need more let me know.

```
Listen 10.0.1.191:80
ServerName server.local:80 (i know a bit stupid but logical for me and it works)
NameVirtualHost 10.0.1.191:80    

<VirtualHost 10.0.1.191:80>
ServerName www.server.local
ServerAlias server.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.1.191:80>
ServerName qtp.server.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/qtp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Cheers

Edit: Actually only the root works, neither virtualhost resolves. ie www.server.local doesn't resolve though server.local does

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ServerName` directive outside of your `<VirtualHost>` containers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing **NameVirtualHost** directive:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

At the moment you're using **IP-based virtual hosting** in your configuration, which doesn't make sense as you use the same IP:port combinations.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought I put that in. I used that link and changed what I had but no success, also updated original question

Comment: What response do you get from the subdomains? Are you able to ping through your subdomains? Or are you always getting the main page?